# Google App Engine PHP Soap Extension doesn't appear to be enabled in phpinfo()

Tags: php, google-app-engine, soap

I get a fatal error when I try to use a Soap Extension function, and when I view phpinfo(), the extension does not appear at all. This is on my local environment. 
How do I figure out why? According to the docs, it should be enabled by default.

Comment: What's your local development environment? win/mac/linux?

Comment: dev environment is on mac

Comment: Thank you for reporting. Soap extension will be added to the Mac SDK in the next release.